# How to ensure that the adapter extending BaseAdapter for a GridView puts the View in a certain column?

Tags: android, calendar

I understand how to set up my Adapter to dynamically add views. But I have one problem, I need a way to ensure that only 7 views are inserted in any given column within that GridView.

My reason for this is because I am creating a calendar view, and as I insert the number of the day, I need to make sure that the don't accidentally get inserted in a column before or after it. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Defines how many columns to show.

in layout, add `android:numColumns`

or

in code, add `setNumColumns(int)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Comment: Is there a way to limit the number of cells per column? I guess thats what I mean, or do I need to just make the size just right to only fit 7 cells per column?

Comment: what is your "cell" and "column"? a calendar has 7 columns.